# Why Nginx can only run the above server after setting virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I wrote two server config in my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file.Those point to different applications.But after I restart my nginx server,it can run the above server only.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Nginx version is 1.6.0.

My config:

```
    upstream app {                                            
        # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously           
        server unix:/usr/share/nginx/html/app1/sockets/unicorn.app1.sock fail_timeout=0;                                                                                                                                               
    }

    server {                                                    
            listen 80;                                              
            index index.html index.htm;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            server_name localhost;                                      
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/app1/public;                          
            try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;                         
            location @app {                                             
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                        
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;                           
                    proxy_redirect off;                                        
                    proxy_pass http://app;                                      
            }          

            error_page 404 /404.html;                                   

            # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html                                                                                                                                                                    
            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;                       
            location = /50x.html {                                      
                root /usr/share/nginx/html/app1;                                 
            }                                                           
            client_max_body_size 4G;                                    
            keepalive_timeout 10;                                            
    }                 

    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration                                                                                                                                                         

    server {                                                    
        listen   80;                                               
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;                                
        index index.php index.html index.htm;                               
        server_name localhost;                                       
        location / {                                               
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;                          
        }                                                          
        error_page 404 /404.html;                                    
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;                                                                                                                                                                                            
        location = /50x.html {                                      
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;                                 
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket                                                                                                                                                         
        location ~ \.php$ {                                         
            try_files $uri = 404;                                       
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;                        
            fastcgi_index index.php;                                    
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;        
            include fastcgi_params;                                    
        }                                                           
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bound both servers to the same `listen 80` port (which is the default HTTP port), and both servers are on the same `server_name localhost` domain.  Therefore, the web server cannot separate HTTP traffic for both targets.

You can solve the problem by either:

- Putting one on a different port e.g. `listen 81;`
- Putting one on a purchased domain e.g. `server_name my.domain.com;`
- Combine the two server blocks into one e.g.

  ```
  location /app1 { ... }
  location /app2 { ... }
  ```

EDIT: If I combine your two server blocks as given, I get the following configuration:

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/usr/share/nginx/html/app1/sockets/unicorn.app1.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    # first app on sub-directory
    location /app1 {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/app1/public;
        index index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

        location @app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/app1;
        }

        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
    }

    # second app on sub-directory
    location /app2 {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri = 404;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Most of the information you need to further refine your configuration can be found under the relevant module in http://wiki.nginx.org/Modules.  The most important modules are HTTP Core, Rewrite, FastCGI, and Index.

Comment: Thank you very much. About `Combine the two server blocks into one`,I can't understand it.Can you tell me how to do if use my config file?